# Autolayout: Element Not Installed For Varying Orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I created a button called "Next Button" seen below...

[image]

It seems to have become disabled/uninstalled for different screen orientations. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look this picture I have the same case with ANY/ANY I have no install item:

[image]

For solve you can remove any hC in the X and click in installed and shows in any/any because is the default.
If you need add more cases and only show in a specific orientation you can change Any/Any and choose for example Regular/Compact and go to right and install or unistal this label or button.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by clicking on it and checking "installed" in the **attributes inspector**.